# PuLP: Using only one item per group

Tags: python, pandas, constraints, solver, pulp

I have a Pandas dataframe that has following values:

```
     Name    Age    City    Points
1    John    24     CHI     35
2    Mary    18     NY      25
.
.
80   Steve   30     CHI     32
```

I'm trying to form a 5 person group that maximizes the sum of points. I'd like to have two constraints: age and city. Maximum age must be under 110 years and there can't be two persons from the same city.

At the moment I have a script that maximizes the points and takes the age constraint into account:

```
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index, cat='Integer', lowBound=0)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("prog", pulp.LpMaximize)

objvals_p = {idx: (df['Points'][idx]) for idx in df.index}
mod += sum([x[idx]*objvals_p[idx] for idx in df.index])

objvals_a = {idx: (df['Age'][idx]) for idx in df.index}
mod += pulp.lpSum([x[idx]*objvals_a[idx] for idx in df.index]) < 110
```

However I can't figure out how to add city constraint into my script.

Any advices for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for city in df['City'].unique():
    sub_idx = df[df['City']==city].index
    mod += pulp.lpSum([x[idx] for idx in sub_idx]) <= 1
```

For each city in the DataFrame, this sum is over a subset of DataFrame (indexed by sub_idx) and this sum should be smaller than or equal to 1 because 2 people from the same city cannot be in the team.

For this (and your other constraint) to work, you need to change the definition of your decision variable. It should be binary; integrality is not enough.

```
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index, 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)
```